# Alterar estado de objeto contendo array interno React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, ecmascript

Bom dia senhores, sou novo no React native e estou com uma grande dúvida a respeito da atualização de um objeto de estado

Eu recebo o objeto em route.params , monto um estado na variavel prod :

```
const [prod, setProd] = useState(route.params ? route.params : { images: [] })
```

e crio um novo estado para o array interno do objeto prod.images

```
const [state, setImages] = useState({ imgArray })
```

os inputs de images são gerados dinamicamente no trecho do .map

os inputs que não sao dinamicos, tem a função de `onChangeText={(title) => { setProd({ ...prod, title }) }}` pra fazer a atualização do estado de prod, e funciona como esperado.

já os inputs dinamicos , `onChangeText={(img) => { inputImages(img, i) }}` eles chamam a função inputImages, que pega o o indice do array imgArray a ser alterado, e o novo valor, e altera o estado de state com a função setImages, quando eu clico em salvar pra ver o conteudo em um console.warn(prod), eu descubro que o objeto prod(estado) foi atualizado com os novos valores que estao em state e imgArray, minha duvida é :

A função setImages, em nenhum momento atualiza  prod.images, ou prod, ela altera state, do trecho `const [state, setImages] = useState({ imgArray })`

porque o objeto prod esta recebendo os novos valores ? o que acontece para o formulario ter esse comportamento ?

obs: removi alguns inputs não dinamicos pra deixar o código mamis enxuto

Em um formulário de produtos, eu recebo seguinte Json

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "title": "perfume Oil",
    "description": "Mega Discount, Impression of Acqua Di Gio by GiorgioArmani concentrated attar perfume Oil",
    "price": 13,
    "discountPercentage": 8.4,
    "rating": 4.26,
    "stock": 65,
    "brand": "Impression of Acqua Di Gio",
    "category": "fragrances",
    "thumbnail": "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/thumbnail.jpg",
    "images": [
    "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/1.jpg",
    "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/2.jpg",
    "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/3.jpg",
    "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/11/thumbnail.jpg"
    ]
}
```

segue código do formulario :

```
import { Button, Icon } from '@rneui/base'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'


export default ({ navigation, route }: any) => {

    const [prod, setProd] = useState(route.params ? route.params : { images: [] })
          
    let imgArray = prod.images

    const [state, setImages] = useState({ imgArray })

    const inputImages = (img: any, index: number) => {
        imgArray[index] = img
        return setImages({imgArray})
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.form}>
                <Text>Nome</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={{}}
                    onChangeText={(title) => { setProd({ ...prod, title }), console.warn(prod) }}
                    placeholder='nome do produto'
                    value={prod.title}
                />
                <Text>Descrição</Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={{}}
                    onChangeText={(description) => { setProd({ ...prod, description }) }}
                    placeholder='descrição do produto'
                    value={prod.description}
                />

                {prod.images.map((p: string, i: number) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={i}>
                            <Text>Imagem {i}</Text>
                            <TextInput
                                style={{}}
                                onChangeText={(img) => { inputImages(img, i) }}
                                placeholder='imagens'
                                value={p}
                            />
                        </View>
                    )
                })}
            </View>
            <Button
                title='Salvar'
                titleStyle={{ color: 'white' }}
                type='solid'
                color='green'
                onPress={() => { console.warn(prod) }}
                icon={<Icon name='save' size={25} color='white' style={{ paddingRight: 5 }} />}
            />
        </ScrollView>


    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        margin: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    form: {
        padding: 30,
    }
})
```

observação final : esse é o trecho versao final e correto que atualiza prod

```
const inputImages = (img: any, index: number) => {
    imgArray[index] = img
    setProd({ ...prod, imgArray })
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.